# Does the German environmental badge apply to other countries of Europe?

Tags: germany, france, automobiles, belgium

I planned the trip that will cover Germany, Belgium and France. I am aware that there are environmental zones in those countries and I need the correct badge for my car to enter them.

So my question is do I need to buy a badge for each country separately or one (German for example) is enough for all countries? And if one is applied then which one is better to have?

Comment: I remember a German bus driver in the UK telling me how the German _Umweltplakette_, which costs a total of 5 Euros, supposedly worked for the central London zone where admission used to cost something like 20 GBP a day. I don't know if this information was true, or if it would still be valid.

Comment: You don't buy them to get it, you buy them to have certified what emission category your car is in (meaning if you have a dirty car you will have a sticker, but can't enter anyways). These rules and categories are different in each country, thus one can't stand for the other.

Comment: For Germany, you can order the badge on [GTÜ site](http://www.gtue.de/apps2/feinstaub/international/index_en.php) for €10 including postage, packaging and VAT.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Belgium, there is only one environmental zone today (November 2017) - center of Antwerpen.

[image: Environmental zone in Antwerpen]

There is no badge for it but unless you drive a car with Belgian or Dutch licence plates you have to register it before driving into this zone (licence plates are automatically controlled with cameras). ([Source](https://www.visitantwerpen.be/en/reaching-antwerp/low-emission-zone), [More information](https://www.slimnaarantwerpen.be/en/lez/where) )

In France, there are environmental zones in Paris, Lyon and Grenoble. To drive into those zones you need a French *Crit'Air* badge. A German *Umweltplakette* is not valid in France.  You can buy Crit'Air [on its official page](https://www.certificat-air.gouv.fr/en/) of French government

Comment: thank you a lot, so I need to register my licence plate to enter the Atwerp center, if I will not enter, then nothing need to be registered for Belgium, is it correct?

Comment: Yes. I added a map of that zone and one more link to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Germany you don't need this green badge in every town. Forget about the yellow and the red badge if you plan to buy one, almost all restricted places want to see the green one. Plan your trip well and try to avoid those cities for which you need the badge and you have some money left for a nice meal. Uh ! Btw. 5€ is only valid at certain shops in Germany. From abroad you have to pay around €20